# Correct translation of "I need some help with my homework."

Tags: translation

I'm a Chinese learner and I wanted to test my skills on Chinese. So I tried to translate this:

> I need some help with my homework.

I tried to translate it and came up with this:

> 我需要一些帮助同我的作业。 (Wǒ xūyào yīxiē bāngzhù tóng wǒ de zuòyè.)

I tried to translate my translation to Google Translate and it returned:

> I need some help with my homework.

But when I switched languages (English to Chinese), Google Translate returned this:

> 我的功课需要一些帮助。(Wǒ de gōngkè xūyào yīxiē bāngzhù.)

So I switched the languages again (Chinese to English), Google Translate returned this:

> My homework needs some help.

I laughed a bit at this, just sharing.

So my problem is, which is the correct translation? **我的功课需要一些帮助。** or **我需要一些帮助同我的作业。**?

Comment: re  **同**  (adj. adv. v.)when used as preposition "(together) with"  occurs before the verb (as "coverb"), for " **help with** " see online dictionaries, e.g iciba:

帮助（某人）做…； 用…来帮助；
协助经营 help with the administration, 帮忙计时  help with the timekeeping,在帮着干杂活helping with odd jobs,帮我翻译helped me with the translation,帮助提供材料和资金 helped with materials and money,给我一笔贷款help with a loan,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**我的功课需要一些帮助** is better than **我需要一些帮助同我的作业**

I ==> 我

need ==> 需要

some ==> 一些 or 某人

help ==> 幫助

my homework ==> 我的功課

So, you can say 「我的功課，需要一些幫助」

Comment: 「我需要幫助我的功課」 is correct for me, so this answer is somehow correct. I understand now. But the last thing you said.「我的功課，需要一些幫助」, 我的功課 means "My homework"; 需要 means "need"; 一些 means "some" and; 幫助 means "help". So clearly it says "My homework needs some help." which is somehow proper but not proper enough in English. But not minding that, I'll mark this answer correct. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Use 「我需要有人幫助我的功課」is much better.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to translate this sentence. The important element of translation is not translating word by word. As long as you can deliver correct message, you should be fine. One example for translating "I need some help with my homework." is 我需要人帮帮我的作业。

Answer (score 1):

I need some help with my homework.
我需要有人帮助我完成家庭作业。
or
我的家庭作业需要有人帮助。

Answer (score 1):

I would say 我写作业需要帮助, or 我需要有人帮我写作业